# Basic likelihood quest: finding the likelihood function for a simple experiment.

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification, maximum-likelihood

The question:

In order to determine the probability of success of a certain experiment, each of one
hundred persons perform a series of these experiments until one results in success.
A model to describe this: the number of attempts $N$ required until the first success
follows a $Geo(p)$-distribution. We wish to estimate $p$ using the maximum likelihood
method.

The data:
[image]

My reasoning:

Let $X_i$ with $i=1, ..., 100$ denote the number of attempts required until the first succes for person $i$. We now consider the follwing probability mass function

$$ P(X_1=x_1, ..., X_{100}=x_{100})=\prod_{i=1}^{100}P(X_i=x_i)=p^{100}\prod_{i=1}^{100}(1-p)^{x_i-1} \\
=p^{100}(1-p)^{30}[(1-p)^{2}]^{15}[(1-p)^{\sum_{i'}x_{i'}-1}]$$

where $x_{i'}\geq4$ and $i'$ the index for the corresponding group of people. The possible answers are

[image]

So the only possible answer would be d, is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your reasoning is not correct.

Recall that the PMF for a geometric distribution with probability $p$ of success that counts the total trials needed to observe the first success, is given by $$\Pr[X = x] = (1-p)^{x-1} p, \quad x \in \{1, 2, \ldots \}.$$
From this we conclude that $$\Pr[X \ge x] = \sum_{k=x}^\infty \Pr[X = x] = p (1-p)^{x-1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p)^k = p (1-p)^{x-1} \frac{1}{1-(1-p)} = (1-p)^{x-1}.$$  We can also see this intuitively since it takes at least $x$ tries to obtain the first success if and only if the first $x-1$ tries are all failures.

Therefore, the likelihood for $p$ given the sample is $$\begin{align}
\mathcal L(p \mid \boldsymbol x) &= \Pr[X = 1]^{40} \Pr[X = 2]^{30} \Pr[X = 3]^{15} \Pr[X \ge 4]^{15} \\
&= ((1-p)^0 p)^{40}((1-p)^1 p)^{30} ((1-p)^2 p)^{15} ((1-p)^3)^{15} \\
&= (1-p)^{30 + 2(15) + 3(15)} p^{40 + 30 + 15} \\
&= p^{85} (1-p)^{105}.
\end{align}$$
Your error lies in counting every person's experiment as contributing a factor of $p$ to the likelihood, when in fact only those people who reported an exact number of trials contribute $p$ to the likelihood.  Those $15$ people who reported at least four trials were needed because their first three failed, do not contribute a factor of $p$.  If instead they all reported *exactly* four trials were needed, then you would get $p^{100}(1-p)^{105}$ as you claim.